# "send-mail: Applet not found" when using mail command on alpine linux

Tags: email, busybox, sendmail, alpine-linux

I am using alpine linux running in a docker container to run a webapp. The webapp is supposed to send emails using the mail command from the command line.

To support this, I have installed mail as follows:

```
apk add mailx
```

When I try to send a message I get the following error:

```
bash-4.3# mail foo@bar.com
Subject: test
EOT
Null message body; hope that's ok
bash-4.3# send-mail: applet not found
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default MTA available in Alpine. Besides mailx, you will also need to install and configure a MTA (Mail Transfer Agent), such as postfix:

```
# apk add postfix
(1/3) Installing db (5.3.28-r0)
(2/3) Installing libsasl (2.1.26-r8)
(3/3) Installing postfix (3.1.3-r0)
Executing postfix-3.1.3-r0.pre-install
Executing busybox-1.25.1-r0.trigger
OK: 8 MiB in 16 packages
```

Start postfix:

```
~ # postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by root: /var/spool/postfix/.
postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by root: /var/spool/postfix/pid
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
```

Send the test message:

```
~ # mail -s "Test" test@boo.com
.
EOT
Null message body; hope that's ok
```

Comment: great. This is very helpful. I am still getting a warning: `bash-4.3# send-mail: warning: smtputf8_enable is true, but EAI support is not compiled in
postdrop: warning: smtputf8_enable is true, but EAI support is not compiled in`, and not receiving the email. Wondering why that is.

Comment: postconf "smtputf8_enable = no" , should do the trick, followed by a restart of Postfix

Comment: correct. Fixed.